# How I replace a text like javascript in c# ...?

Tags: javascript, c#

I am new to C# programming. I previously wrote Javascript. I want to replace a text in C# just like in JavaScript. Here is my JavaScript Code:

```
var str = "this is my text";
str = str.replace(/\b(\w)/g,function(matched){
   return matched.toUpperCase();
});
```

How is this done in C#? Thanks in Advance and sorry for my poor english.

Comment: See [RegEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program {
    static void Main() {
        string text = "this is my text";

        Regex rx = new Regex(@"\b(\w)");

        string result = rx.Replace(text, (Match m) => {
                return m.ToString().ToUpper().ToString();
        } );

        Console.WriteLine(result);// "This Is My Text"
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your JS code you want to capitalize first letter of each word. In c# it is better to do in a different way.

```
string lipsum1 = "this is my text";

// Creates a TextInfo based on the "en-US" culture.
TextInfo textInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US",false).TextInfo;

// Changes a string to titlecase.
Console.WriteLine("\"{0}\" to titlecase: {1}", 
                  lipsum1, 
                  textInfo.ToTitleCase( lipsum1 )); 

// Will output: "this is my text" to titlecase: This Is My Text
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several scenarios where you replace a string:

1. Every instance is replaced This is important. The Replace method changes every instance of the specified substring. We must assign the result to a variable.

   ```
   using system;
   class Program
   {
      static void Main()
      {
      const string s = "Coding code is about writing Coding code the
                        right way";
      Console.WriteLine(s);
      string v = s.Replace("Coding", "Testing");
      Console.WriteLine(v);
      }
   }
   ```

// Input: Coding code is about writing Coding code the right way

// Output: Testing code is about writing Testing code the right way

2. Replacing just a single string Replace word (and following space) with a new word.We assign to the Replace method's result.

   ```
   using System;
   class Program
   {
     static void Main()
     {
       const string input = "key logger";
       Console.WriteLine("::BEFORE::");
       Console.WriteLine(input);
       string output = input.Replace("key ", "keyword ");
       Console.WriteLine("::AFTER::");
       Console.WriteLine(output);    
     }
   }
   ```

// Output:

::BEFORE::
   key logger

::AFTER::
   keyword logger

3. Using StringBuilder to replace strings

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Text;

   class Program
   {
     static void Main()
     {
       const string s = "This is an example.";

       // Create new StringBuilder from string.
       StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(s);
       Console.WriteLine(b);

       // Replace the first word.
       // ... The result doesn't need assignment.
       b.Replace("This", "Here");
       Console.WriteLine(b);

       // Insert the string at the beginning.
       b.Insert(0, "Sentence: ");
       Console.WriteLine(b);
     }
   }
   ```

Output :

This is an example.

Here is an example.

Sentence: Here is an example.

Answer (score -1):

you use the String.Replace method 
Syntax:

```
String s = "This is an example.";
s = s.replace("is","was");
```

s will now say : This was an example.

Comment: His JS is not replacing `is` to `was`. It is capitalizing first letter of each work